# xmlhttp.readyState returns 2 even though xmlhttp.status equals 200

Tags: javascript, php

I'm sending an email through ajax to contact php. Php script sends the email successfully, but ajax xmlhttp.readyState is keep returing 2 even though xmlhttp.status is 200.

```
params = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message + "&telephone=" + telephone;

xmlhttp.open("POST", "contact.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){

        if(xmlhttp.responseText == "fill_form"){
            note.innerHTML = "Please fill the required fields properly";
            return;
        }

        if(xmlhttp.responseText == "Sent"){
            serverMessage.innerHTML = "Thanks. If it is a request or complaint we well get back to you soon";
        }
    }
    else{
        serverMessage.innerHTML = "Some internal error occured while sending the email. Please try again later";
        $('#myModal').modal('show')
    }

    submitBtn.innerHTML = "SEND MESSAGE";
    submitBtn.disabled = false;
}
```

Contact.php

```
<?php

$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
$telephone=$_POST['telephone'];

$mail_to_send_to = "abc@gmail.com";
$feed_back_mail = "name@myDomainName.com";

if (empty($name) || empty($email)|| empty($message))
{
    echo "fill_form";
}
else{

    $from="From:$feed_back_mail"."\r\n"."Reply-To:$email"."\r\n" ;
    $subject="Users feed back Contact";

    if(empty($telephone)){
        $telephone = "No telephone sent my user";    
    }

    $message = "Telephone: $telephone\r\nSender's Email : $email \r\n \r\n$message \r\n";

$isSent = mail($mail_to_send_to, $subject, $message, $from);

    if($isSent){
        echo $isSent;
    }
    else{
        echo "not_sent";
    }
}
```

?>

What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that your `onreadystatechange` callback will be called **multiple times** as the ready state changes. Your current code responds to the *first* callback expecting it to be done. But it's quite normal for you to get a call *before* that with `readyState` 2 ("headers received").

So just wait until you get `readyState` 4:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        // Done, what happened?
        if(xmlhttp.status == 200){
            // All good
        }
        else{
            // Something went wrong
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

`xmlhttp.readyState` Holds the status of the XMLHttpRequest.

It can be from 0 to 4:

```
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready
```

Where as `xmlhttp.status` indicates the status code of the request you have just made.

More from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState)

The XMLHttpRequest.readyState property returns the state an XMLHttpRequest client is in.

```
0   UNSENT              Client has been created. open() not called yet.
1   OPENED              open() has been called.
2   HEADERS_RECEIVED    send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
3   LOADING             Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
4   DONE                The operation is complete.
```

> **2** indicates *send() has been called and the response headers have been received.*
> **4** indicates *The fetch operation is complete. This could mean that either the data transfer has been completed successfully or failed.* 
>   So you should always wait for readyState **4**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState